# Gostaria de saber como utilizo Swing

Tags: java, swing

Estou aprendendo Java Eclipse e gostaria de saber como faço para usar Swing.

É preciso instalar? Como funciona?

Comment: Dependendo do componente que for utlizar é necessario fazer o `import` dele. Pode começar com um exemplo simples como esse: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "teste");`

Comment: Comece instalando o plugin Window Builder. Vá em Help > Install New Software. Em Work With, escolha http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna (caso sua versão seja o Luna). Marque as opção WindowBuilder que estão abaixo de General Purpose Tools.

Comment: A suspensão dessa pergunta está sendo discutida [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2686/voc%C3%AAs-n%C3%A3o-gostam-de-um-swing).

Comment: Desculpe ser chato, mas sou a favor de manter esta questão fechada. Só para se ter uma ideia, tenho um livro inteiro dentro de uma caixa e ele poderia ser a resposta para sua pergunta, e portanto ela é ampla demais. Além disso, você pergunta "como faço para usar Swing?", mas usar em qual sentido? Sem dizer exatamente o que você quer dizer com isso, iria da cabeça de cada um que vier responder, e boa parte das respostas não seria o que você quis dizer. Portanto sua pergunta é muito vaga.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça qual é a sua dúvida pois cada pessoa teve um entendimento diferente sobre ela e provavelmente se ela estivesse aberta você já teria recebido várias respostas que possivelmente não te ajudariam no que você precisa.

Answer (score 3):

vou tentar responder separadamente as perguntas. Primeiro a pergunta mais acertiva.

> E preciso instalar, como funciona?

Para começar a aprender o funcionamento da swing não é preciso instalar nada. Tendo em vista que você já tem a JDK instalada.

Vou deixar um exemplo bem simples aqui com o código que o @rray postou, só que um pouco mais detalhado.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "teste");
    }
}
```

> Boa noite, estou aprendendo java eclipse, e gostaria de saber como faço para usar swing?

Cara, quando eu comecei a aprender swing, basicamente eu li uma apostila, segui os exemplos e depois fui buscando o que eu precisava dentro da [documentação do java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). Acho que a parte da documentação do java é a mais importante. Pensando que talvez você não teve nenhum contato com a documentação, vou deixar um link para a documentação do [javax.swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: De fato não é obrigatório instalar mais nada para sair usando o Swing, mas você acha que está sendo muito sádico (com o perdão da palavra, mas já que o assunto era Swing, rs...) em sugerir que ele faça tudo na unha? Tem o WindowBuilder que ajuda e muito na criação da UI.

Comment: Olha um jeito mais simples de brincar com swing é usar o netbeans pois ele ja tem os componentes de modo visual onde vc arrasta os componentes e cria as açoes apartir do netbeans vale a pena conhecer.